# Error 400 Spotify API - "Only Valid bearer authentication supported"

Tags: javascript, server, fetch-api, spotify, spotify-app

I was trying to display playlist names, description and images of a search query in spotify but I keep getting this error, so nothing renders. It was working earlier and then abruptly stopped working for some reason. I made sure my client Id and secret where correct, even the token as well, but for some reason the second fetch call causes a bad request even though the token is set to the bearer.  Can some one  help me with this? I am also seeing now that I am getting a 404 error on the first request.

TI used a secondary function to retrieve the token so that it could not be changed by the client, however it still doesn't work properly.

```
const _getToken = async () => {
    
    const result = await fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
            'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa(clientId + ':' + clientSecret)
        },
        body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    });

    const data = await result.json();
    return data.access_token;
}


function getTokenPub(){
    return _getToken();
}


fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=similar%2520artists%2520to%2520frank%2520ocean&type=playlist&limit=5', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + getTokenPub()}
}).then(res=> {
    return res.json()
})
.then((data) => {
    (data.playlists.items).forEach(user =>{
        const markup = `<li>${user.name}</li>`;
        document.querySelector('.desc').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup)
        const markupDesc = `<li> ${user.description} </li>`
        document.querySelector('.desc').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markupDesc)
        const markupLink = `<input type="button" onclick="location.href='${user.external_urls.spotify}'" value="Listen" />`
        document.querySelector('.desc').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markupLink)
        const markupImg = `<img width=100 height =100 style="border-radius: 50px" src="${user.images[0].url}">`
        document.querySelector('.desc').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markupImg)
    })
    console.log(data)
})
.catch(error => console.log('ERROR'))
```

Comment: _getToken is async, so in return getTokenPub is too.. getTokenPub().then(token => fetch(...))

Comment: Oh i see, I tried putting the result of _getToken in place of getTokenPub() in the second fetch call and I still get a 404 and 400 error